# Delphi: get the max integer directory name in a certain path

Tags: delphi, winapi

in a certain path (eg. `C:\foo\bar\`), I have a undefined number of directory named with a integer, eg.:

```
C:\foo\bar\0\
C:\foo\bar\1\
C:\foo\bar\2\
C:\foo\bar\9\
C:\foo\bar\10\
C:\foo\bar\100\
```

i would get max integer directory named in `C:\foo\bar\` path, in this case is 100.

My code works, but is slow:

```
function GetMaxDir(const APath : String) : integer;
var
   LList    : TStringDynArray;
   I        : Integer;
   EndFor   : Integer;
   CurrDir  : string;
   CurrVer  : Integer;
begin
   Result := -1;

   if not DirectoryExists(APath) then Exit;

   LList   := TDirectory.GetDirectories(APath);
   EndFor  := Length(LList) - 1;
   CurrVer := 0;

   for I := 0 to EndFor do begin
      CurrVer := 0;
      CurrDir := ExtractFileName(LList[I]); // return path leaf (the integer)

      TryStrToInt(CurrDir, CurrVer);

      if CurrVer > Result then Result := CurrVer;
   end;
end;
```

usage, eg.:

```
var
  aMaxDir : integer;
begin
  aMaxDir := GetMaxDir('C:\foo\bar\'); // return 100
```

Is this the faster way?

Comment: Can you change the way the folders are being named? If you can change them to use three or four digits (eg., `001`, `002`, `010`, `100`), you can just sort the array and then grab the last element.

Comment: Enumerating the directories is the cost here. Sorting the array as suggested by @KenWhite will be even slower. That will be O(n log n) but your search is O(n). Ignoring the return value of `TryStrToInt` is poor. Don't do that. Why do you believe that you can do better than this? What is your performance target? How long does this take? Where are the files? Local or network? Are the only directories of this form, or are there many others not of this form?

Comment: @KenWhite no i can't change the name of directories

Comment: @DavidHeffernan directory are stored locally. `Why do you believe that you can do better than this? ` because i'm a delphi newbie :D

Comment: A more general point is that it whenever you talk about performance, you should never say "this is slow, make it faster." You need to quantify performance, show us how to replicate the performance, explain the target performance, and at least give some indication of why you might expect to achieve that target. Bland, "I want it to be faster" statements don't tend to lead to constructive questions.

Comment: That's not a good reason. I don't see any particular reason for you to expect significant performance benefit. Where do you think that the performance could be improved?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to know only if exists a better way to improve performance to this funcion...

Comment: Well, I doubt it, because you'll need to enumerate the directories come what may.

Comment: No Need to sort: do a findfirst/findnext/findclose. and on each name returned do a TryStrToInt() and check the flags that it is a directory. When it is a umber, check if it is higher than the highest up to now and keep the maximum value. This will open onlya single handle (on the parent dir) and not one per file tested...

Comment: @Ritseart That's precisely what the code in the question does

Comment: If you are the one adding the files, then keep the names elsewhere, such as a database or even a text file.  Or just keep the max-number somewhere and update it as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer NO, because as far as I know in windows you don't have a low level API that allows you to get the first file based on a specified sorting criteria.

Comment: `TDirectory.GetDirectories` is implemented by calling `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` etc. So how could calling that directly help?

Comment: It does't help, it was just to explain that the only API we have on windows doesn't allow that .

Comment: You said that you could get the results faster by calling the same API as is already being called. That sounds wrong. Please correct that second paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Assuming an NTFS file system, you could read the *$MFT* ([Master File Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Master_File_Table)) directly, and parse that instead of enumerating all directories. This *might* improve performance. Is it worth it? Depends on the specifications, which the OP is failing to publish.